# Ruby\Rails sandboxing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a case, when the text from the DB field should be "evaled" in the sandbox mode - with whitelist of methods and constants, allowed to invoke.

Gem https://github.com/tario/shikashi fits to this perfectly, but it seems to me, that it's abandoned.

I even can't use run `Basic Example 2` (only `Basic Example 1` works fine):

```
require "rubygems"
require "shikashi"

include Shikashi

def foo
    # privileged code, can do any operation
    print "foo\n"
end

s = Sandbox.new
priv = Privileges.new

# allow execution of foo in this object
priv.object(self).allow :foo

# allow execution of method :times on instances of Fixnum
priv.instances_of(Fixnum).allow :times

#inside the sandbox, only can use method foo on main and method times on instances of Fixnum
s.run(priv, "2.times do foo end")
```

Because it fails with an Error `Cannot invoke method foo on object of class Object (SecurityError)`

This gem uses another gem `evalhook` that looks for me complicated in order to fix the issue. There are another gems like this one but they are even more abandoned.

As far as I understood using `$SAFE` is not a good idea, because it has vulnerabilities.

Are there another approaches for such feature? Maybe manipulating with `Binding` object?

Comment: [treetop](https://github.com/nathansobo/treetop) seems to be a more popular choice, regardless of it's development activeness.

Comment: Why do you need to eval user-generated Ruby script? Are you building some kind of 'try Ruby' system?

Comment: @EugZol, on my project there are a lot of business logic, that is easier to represent as few lines of Ruby code, instead of huge configuration forms on the web UI.

Comment: Does it have to be ruby, though? Might as well use Lua or JS. They were built to be embedded.

Comment: @TamerShlash, thank you! But it seems to me, that this will take more afford to implement own language, instead of using Ruby.

Comment: I second advice to switch to a language which is inherently supposed to be run inside of a sandbox. Well, it's more than possible that even [Liquid](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid) could be enough for your task.

Comment: @EugZol, thank you for your answer! As far as I understood Liquid is designed for building templates and the result of it's job is ready to render template. How can I use it if I would like to invoke methods of Ruby object in order to make my mini-DSL?

Comment: Well, you can't build arbitrary DSL with Liquid. But you could add your own liquid 'tags' and 'filters'. What's the value in your DSL, are you sure that any established templating language will be worse than it? :)

Comment: @EugZol: templating languages suck at expressing business logic (who would've thought, right?)

Comment: If you are sure that what logic do you have in your mind deserves to be named *business logic*, Lua and JS were suggested as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was not so hard to solve without any gems. The idea is that you have whitelist of methods and constants `WHITELIST` and this class checks, if all methods and constants are in the whitelist

```
# gem install 'parser'

require 'parser/current'

class CodeValidator
  attr_reader :errors, :source

  WHITELIST = {:send => [:puts, :+, :new], :const => [:String]}

  class Parser::AST::Node
    def value
      return children[1] if [:send, :const].include? type
      fail NotImplementedError
    end
  end


  def initialize(source)
    @errors = []
    @source = source
  end

  def valid?
    !insecure_node?(root_node)
  end

  private

  def exclude_node?(node)
    blacklisted_node_types.include?(node.type) && !WHITELIST[node.type].include?(node.value)
  end

  def blacklisted_node_types
    WHITELIST.keys
  end

  def insecure_node?(node)
    return !!add_error_for_node(node) if exclude_node?(node)
    node.children.each { |child_node| return true if child_node.class == Parser::AST::Node && insecure_node?(child_node) }
    false
  end

  def root_node
    @root_node ||= Parser::CurrentRuby.parse source
  end

  def add_error_for_node(node)
    errors << "#{node.type} not allowed: #{node.value}"
  end
end

c = CodeValidator.new("s = 'hello ' + String.new('world'); puts s.inspect")
p c.valid? # => false
p c.errors # => ["send not allowed: inspect"]
```